# Would a dead internal audio card kill hdmi audio output as well?

Tags: audio, hdmi, sound-card

I've got a old gigabyte motherboard. The internal audio card is mostly dead since none of the audio drivers worked so far. Ive got an Sapphire 7850 video card and was wondering if I could replace the internal audio via hdmi cable.

I've already tried to do this by connecting the pc to my Sony TV via hdmi, but even after changing the default audio output to hdmi, I've still got no audio. Am I missing something? So does this mean a dead internal audio card will kill the hdmi audio as well? Looking for suggestions to fix this issue. Final option would be purchasing an external audio card.

Comment: No, they're independent devices. HDMI audio is provided by the graphics card and, in order for it to work properly, it may need drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've updated the amd radeon drivers to the latest version and in audio settings switched to hdmi audio as well. Still no sound on the tv or the monitor. Any other things I should try?

Comment: make sure you have no cable attached in the 3.5mm headphone jacks and if possible try a different HDMI cable as well, sometimes its just the cables  !!